# Compile error catching exceptions in the same catch clause

Tags: java, exception, runtimeexception

I have two RuntimeExceptions as you can see below:

```
@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyCustomRuntimeException1 extends RuntimeException {

    private final String message;
    private final int code;
}

@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyCustomRuntimeException2 extends RuntimeException {

    private final String message;
    private final int code;
}
```

Then I have my doSomethingMethod where I catch them in the same catch clause:

```
public void doSomething() {

[....]
[....]
 
    try {

         [....]
         [....]    

    } catch (MyCustomRuntimeException1 | MyCustomRuntimeException2 ex) {
            log.error("!! doSomething: An error occurred", ex);
            var code = ex.getCode();
            var message = ex.getMessage();

            [......]
            [......]
    }
}
```

I'm receiving a compile-time error that says `Cannot resolve method 'getCode' in 'RuntimeException'` on the following line:

```
var code = ex.getCode();
```

On the other hand, this snippet code works properly:

```
public void doSomething() {

[....]
[....]
 
    try {

         [....]
         [....]    

    } catch (MyCustomRuntimeException1 ex) {
            log.error("!! doSomething: An error occurred", ex);
            var code = ex.getCode();
            var message = ex.getMessage();

            [......]
            [......]

    } catch (MyCustomRuntimeException2 ex) {
            log.error("!! doSomething: An error occurred", ex);
            var code = ex.getCode();
            var message = ex.getMessage();

            [......]
            [......]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what happens here, when you have a multi-catch clause, is that the inferred type of the exception parameter, `ex` in your case, is the nearest common *superclass* of the exceptions listed in the multi-catch.  I couldn't find this explicitly documented in the language reference, but it is implied in at least one place.  See the example at the end of [14.20. the try statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20)

So the nearest common superclass of your two exception classes is `RuntimeException`, which of course does not have a `getCode()` method.

As @VasilyLiakovsky suggests in a comment, you could create an abstract intermediate class that defines the common methods you'd like to share.

Comment: This probably can be fixed by introducing intermediate exception class with `getCode()`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are extending the `getCode()` method which is present in both MyCustomRuntimeException1 and MyCustomRuntimeException2 , the compiler is confused as to which runtime exception `getCode()` are you trying to point ? .

To resolve this, you can

i) specify the class name and the method that you are trying to call.